# Flutter transition like iOS 13 modal full screen

Tags: flutter, dart, modal-dialog, transition, router

I would like to have the iOS-Modal-Transition where the new screen animates from the bottom and the old screen is being pushed behind. I found this very promising package:

[modal_bottom_sheet](https://github.com/jamesblasco/modal_bottom_sheet)

This is the function I am using to show the modal:

```
showCupertinoModalBottomSheet(
                  expand: true,
                  context: context,
                  builder: (context) => Container(
                    color: AppColors.blue,
                  ),
                );
```

However this is not working a 100% correctly as the view behind is not being pushed in the back.

What am I missing here? Let me know if anything is unclear!

Here is some more of my code:

This is my whole page, from where I would like to have the transition:

```
    class _MonthPageState extends State<MonthPage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: AppColors.secondary,
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Stack(
          children: [
            ...
            Positioned(
              bottom: 10,
              right: 20,
              child: Hero(
                tag: widget.month.name + 'icon',
                child: AddButton(
                  onTapped: () {
                    showCupertinoModalBottomSheet(
                      expand: true,
                      context: context,
                      builder: (context) => Container(
                        color: AppColors.blue,
                      ),
                    );
                  },
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

And this is my Router:

```
    class AppRouter {
  static Route<dynamic> generateRoute(RouteSettings settings) {
    switch (settings.name) {
      case '/':
        return MaterialWithModalsPageRoute(
          builder: (context) => HomePage(),
        );
      case '/month':
        final Month month = settings.arguments as Month;
        return _buildTransitionToMonthPage(month);
      default:
        return MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (_) => Scaffold(
            body: Center(
              child: Text('No route defined for ${settings.name}'),
            ),
          ),
        );
    }
  }

  static PageRouteBuilder _buildTransitionToMonthPage(Month month) {
    return PageRouteBuilder(
      transitionDuration: Duration(milliseconds: 450),
      reverseTransitionDuration: Duration(milliseconds: 450),
      pageBuilder: (BuildContext context, Animation<double> animation,
          Animation<double> secondaryAnimation) {
        return MonthPage(
          month: month,
        );
      },
      transitionsBuilder: (BuildContext context, Animation<double> animation,
          Animation<double> secondaryAnimation, Widget child) {
        return FadeTransition(opacity: animation, child: child);
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order to get that pushing behind animation, you need to use `CupertinoScaffold` alongside with `CupertinoPageScaffold`, e.g.

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return CupertinoScaffold(
      transitionBackgroundColor: Colors.white,
      body: Builder(
        builder: (context) => CupertinoPageScaffold(
          backgroundColor: Colors.white,
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              Center(
                child: ElevatedButton(
                    child: Text('show modal'),
                    onPressed: () =>
                        CupertinoScaffold.showCupertinoModalBottomSheet(
                          expand: true,
                          context: context,
                          backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                          builder: (context) => Container(
                              color: Colors.white,
                              child: Center(
                                child: ElevatedButton(
                                  onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context)
                                      .popUntil((route) =>
                                          route.settings.name == '/'),
                                  child: Text('return home'),
                                ),
                              )),
                        )),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: Thanks but how can apply that to my case? I tried wrapping my Scaffolt in a CupertinoScaffold but that didn‘t do anything

Comment: Just do it vice-versa, wrap the `CupertinoScaffold` in a `Scaffold` @Chris

Comment: Tried that as well. Didn’t change anything either

Comment: I don't know how your code looks like now, but you don't need to implement the animation yourself. Just use the code in my answer and change the routes. Maybe that's the problem.. @Chris

Comment: I tried that :( but simply can not apply it to my case. My code is above, that’s pretty much it. Your code is from the example right ? That’s the exact transition  I mean

Comment: Can you share the updated code somehow? @Chris

Comment: CupertinoScaffold is deprecated ?